# How to source init.lua without restarting neovim

Tags: lua, config, neovim

Is there a clean way to reload a neovim init.lua config and all its modules (using the `require()` function) without restarting neovim?

I've read on another post that `:luafile $MYVIMRC` was supposed to accomplish just that but it doesn't reload those cached files unfortunately. I'm hoping to setup a keymap like I used to have in my previous `init.vim` config. Something along the lines of:

```
local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }

vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<leader><CR>", ":luafile $MYVIMRC<CR>", opts)
```

I'm on nvim v0.8.0.

Answer (score 16):

Try to run this command :

```
:luafile %
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. Doesn't `%`  target the active buffer though? I'm trying to assign a keymap to source my init.lua file (including modules) from any location.

Answer (score 6):

If found an answer from [creativenull](https://github.com/creativenull) on [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/puuskh/how_to_reload_my_lua_config_while_using_neovim/) that seems to work well. I ended up creating a small module called `reload.lua`:

```
function _G.ReloadConfig()
  for name,_ in pairs(package.loaded) do
    if name:match('^user') and not name:match('nvim-tree') then
      package.loaded[name] = nil
    end
  end

  dofile(vim.env.MYVIMRC)
  vim.notify("Nvim configuration reloaded!", vim.log.levels.INFO)
end
```

That gets imported in `init.lua`:

```
require 'user.reload'
```

And for which I added a keymap:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<leader><CR>", "<cmd>lua ReloadConfig()<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = false })
```

Note 1: in the example above your lua files need to be contained in a *user* folder: `~/.config/nvim/lua/user/`. That's also where `reload.lua` lives.

Note 2: I think it's possible to use the `not name:match('exclude-me')` regex syntax to exclude problematic modules.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `:luafile <filename>` for this.
See `:h :luafile` for more information.

Comment: Right, the issue I'm facing is that modules are cached when using the `require()` import and simply executing the `:luafile` command doesn't reload those modules. Will update my post to clarify this point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that also includes reloading the files in the `after/` directory:

My `~/.config/nvim` folder tree:

```
.
├── after
│  ├── ftplugin
│  └── plugin
│     ├── telescope.lua
│     └── treesitter.lua
├── init.lua
├── lua
│  └── user
│     ├── init.lua
│     ├── maps.lua
│     ├── options.lua
│     └── plugins.lua
└── plugin
   └── packer_compiled.lua
```

my `~/.config/nvim.init.lua`:

```lua
require('user')


--- Reload the entire configuration
function reload_config()
    for name,_ in pairs(package.loaded) do
        if name:match('^user') then
            package.loaded[name] = nil
        end
    end

    require('user')

    -- Reload after/ directory
    local glob = vim.fn.stdpath('config') .. '/after/**/*.lua'
    local after_lua_filepaths = vim.fn.glob(glob, true, true)

    for _, filepath in ipairs(after_lua_filepaths) do
        dofile(filepath)
    end

    vim.notify("Nvim configuration reloaded!", vim.log.levels.INFO)
end
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader><leader><leader>x', reload_config)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure yet. I am using mapping  :w | so % to source current file
[sourcing file keymap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCCfH.png)

--update --
this works in only config file

like this hope this help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer didn't work for me when I have a keymap, comment it out and type `:w | so %<cr>`. This seems to work when modifying or adding additional keymap lines, but not removing them or commenting them out.

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/tkkj2v/comment/i1rnkoq/) works for me on Neovim v0.7.2.

```
-- Add modules here
local modules = {
  "user.options",
  "user.keymaps",
}

-- Refresh module cache
for k, v in pairs(modules) do
  package.loaded[v] = nil
  require(v)
end
```

You can then config your keymap to refresh $MYVIMRC as follows:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<leader><CR>", ":luafile $MYVIMRC<CR>", opts)
```

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong but this doesn't clear the cache does it?

Comment: @mduboule You seem to be right about that. I just tested this in my init.lua, and when I comment out lines of my keymaps, for example and then `:source %` it, my changes still down take effect, but if I were to make changes to what the key actually does, and `:source %`, then my changes go into effect.